# Vega Simple geopoints in Vega

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, vega

I'm trying to understand how Vega works by trying out things in its integration with Kibana. (using 6.3).

I would want, first, to understand how things work starting by showing simple geopoints on a map. My ultimate goal is to be able to draw shapes and geopoints.

I'm using the build vega graph tool provided by Kibana.

**How the data looks like**

```
{
  "_index": "myindex",
  "_type": "mytype",
  "_id": "some_data_id",
  "_version": 1,
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    // other fields ...
    "location": {
      "geoPosition": {
        "lon": -120.40713879154383,
        "lat": 34.930076722390865
      },
      "country": "country_name",
      "geoArea": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              -120.4093517762316,
              34.92910658338185
            ],
            [
              -120.4049810371925,
              34.92909830256884
            ],
            [
              -120.4049258068561,
              34.93102254256107
            ],
            [
              -120.40934245466,
              34.9310551422129
            ],
            [
              -120.4093517762316,
              34.92910658338185
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
    // other fields ...
  }
}
```

**My pathetic attempt**

```
{
  "$schema": "https://vega.github.io/schema/vega/v3.0.json"
  "config": {
    "kibana": { "type": "map", "delayRepaint": false }
  }
  "data": [ 
    {
      "name": "points"
      "url": {
        "index": "myindex"
        "body": {
          "_source": ["location"]
          "query": {
            "match_all": {}
          }
        }
      }
      "format": { "type": "json", "property": "hits.hits" }
    }
  ]
  "transform": {
    "type": "geopoint"
    "fields": ["geoPosition.lat", "geoPosition.lon"]
  }
  "marks": [
    {
      "type": "symbol"
      "from": { data: "points" }
      "encode": {
        "update":{
          "x": { "field": "x" }
          "y": { "field": "y" }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

**Current result**

- List item
- Map shows correctly
- Points seem to show, but at (0, 0) I guess - Look on top left corner, blue dots should be the geopoints
  [image: dots top left]

**My additional questions**

- I'm not sure how to use properly Vega debugging for this. I've looked at `VEGA_DEBUG.view.getState()`, `VEGA_DEBUG.view._runtime` and `VEGA_DEBUG.view.data('points')` but I cannot properly understand the dataflow. Where can I see the transform output to verify it's "clear" ? Basically this question could be `how would you have debugged this simple issue`

Answer (score 0):

Wow this is an old question... Vega/Elastic is super unsupported so it's a shame nobody could get to this earlier.

The step you're missing is the step where you convert your lat/lon to (x,y) co-ordinates that Vega can use for the map.

This section:

```
"transform": {
    "type": "geopoint"
    "fields": ["geoPosition.lat", "geoPosition.lon"]
}
```

Should be something like this:

```
transform: [
    {
      from: points              // The name of your data object
      type: geopoint
      projection: projection
      fields: ["geoPosition.lat", "geoPosition.lon"]
    }
    {
      type: "formula", expr: "[datum.x, datum.y]", as: "center"
    }
    {
      type: "formula", expr: "{x:datum.center[0], y:datum.center[1]}", as: "centerDict"
    }
]
```

That will give you a centerDict object that represents the [x, y] object which Vega will map properly.  It also will add `point.x` and `point.y` which individually represent the x and y values.

Once you have that you can do this

```
"marks": [
    {
      "type": "symbol"
      "from": { data: "points" }
      "encode": {
        "update":{
          "x": "datum.x"
          "y": "datum.y"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
```

I haven't tested this with your data, but I have something similar so it *should* work.

Good luck!